# How to convert multiple videos into AVI one after another

Tags: ffmpeg

I have many folders with 6 or more videos each. I am currently using this code to convert them into avi:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec mpeg4 -qscale:v 1 -aspect 16:9 output.avi
```

Instead of typing out that code for every single video, is there a code I can use that would convert all the videos in the folder one after another? I am using Windows.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Crossposted on askubuntu.com: [Can you edit multiple videos at the same time using ffmpeg?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/853636/can-you-edit-multiple-videos-at-the-same-time-using-ffmpeg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a loop in shell using your current method to convert .mp4 into .avi . If you have other formats and filename extensions, you'll have to improve it:

```
for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -vcodec mpeg4 -qscale:v 1 -aspect 16:9 "$(basename "$i" .mp4).avi"; done
```

So in a file with some spaces:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in *.mp4; do
    ffmpeg -i "$i" -vcodec mpeg4 -qscale:v 1 -aspect 16:9 "$(basename "$i" .mp4).avi"
done
```

i is the variable iterating over all files matching *.mp4. The basename command removes the .mp4 extension, then we can add .avi instead. All the quotes are there to handle any kind of file, including files with space or other special characters without derailing the whole process. $() which stands for the output of the command inside can be quoted and still have quotes inside without problem.

Comment: OP is using Windows. If you can use bash then parameter expansion can be used instead of the additional `baseline` process: `"${i%.*}.avi"`

Comment: Nice trick. I tend to avoid using bash (over sh) but sometimes it seems it really simplifies things

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to convert all videos in one folder that has not already been converted. If it find the file already exists in the destination folder it skips the file. I used a combination of my own knowledge, the web, and chatgtb to make the bat file.

designed to be run from a .bat file in windows.

Make sure you change the source folder and destination folder to your folder paths.

**set "file_extensions="** lets you pick as many video formats to convert as you want. Enter them with a space in between like **set "file_extensions= .mkv .mov .avi"**

**h264_nvenc** section in the ffmpeg command uses your video card (GPU) instead of your CPU. There is another post that lists different options for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38373180/is-ffmpeg-running-in-cpu-or-gpu)

My example is also converting to mp4 with relatively low quality. You can change the mp4's to avi and it will convert to avi. You can also adjust the quality settings to your liking.

```
@echo off

REM Set the source folder path
set "source_folder=C:\source\folder"

REM Set the destination folder path
set "destination_folder=C:\destination\folder"

REM Set the list of file extensions to include
set "file_extensions=.mp4 .mkv"

REM Loop through each file extension in the list
for %%x in (%file_extensions%) do (
    REM Loop through each video file with the current extension in the source folder
    for %%a in ("%source_folder%\*%%x") do (
        REM Extract the filename with extension
        set "filename=%%~nxa"

        REM Check if the output file already exists
        if not exist "%destination_folder%\%%~na.mp4" (
            REM Convert video to MP4 using FFmpeg
            ffmpeg -i "%%~a" -c:v h264_nvenc -preset medium -crf 23 -c:a aac -b:a 128k "%destination_folder%\%%~na.mp4"


        ) else (
            echo Skipping conversion of "%%~nxa" - Output file already exists.
        )
    )
)
```